# Plotting Line graph from a Series of 3 column: Matplotlib

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a df which i have manipulated as below

```
genres = ['Adventure','Action','Thriller','Science Fiction','Comedy']

df_genre_sum = df_genre.groupby(['genre','release_year'])['revenue'].sum()[genres]

print(df_genre_sum)
```

It gives me result something like :

[image: img]

Now, How can I draw a graph where I can see line plot with all genres in different colors with

X axis  = Years

Y axis = Revenue

I am new to matplotlib, I know to draw graph when series has `index` and `value` but this series has another level inside it.

### Update

> {'Action': {1984: 735328023.0,
>     1985: 152427960.0,
>     1987: 191185897.0,
>     1989: 962338821.0,
>     1990: 381293845.0,
>     1992: 14358033.0,
>     1993: 212954613.0,
>     1995: 418194034.0,
>     1996: 959696788.0,
>     1997: 967263794.0},
>    'Adventure': {1984: 361744356.0,
>     1985: 533537722.0,
>     1987: 191185897.0,
>     1989: 1002823860.0,
>     1990: 244527783.0,
>     1992: 504050219.0,
>     1993: 1133054613.0,
>     1995: 418194034.0,
>     1996: 678894988.0,
>     1997: 922401607.0},
>    'Comedy': {1984: 295212467.0,
>     1985: 381109762.0,
>     1987: 38119483.0,
>     1989: 372485039.0,
>     1990: 721212258.0,
>     1992: 518408252.0,
>     1993: 212954613.0,
>     1995: 390174654.0,
>     1996: 353602675.0,
>     1997: 680494326.0},
>    'Science Fiction': {1984: 402328023.0,
>     1985: 381109762.0,
>     1987: 38119483.0,
>     1989: 372485039.0,
>     1990: 244527583.0,
>     1992: 14358033.0,
>     1993: 1079155768.0,
>     1995: 73959291.0,
>     1996: 293648382.0,
>     1997: 760510868.0},
>    'Thriller': {1984: 78371200.0,
>     1985: 152427960.0,
>     1987: 191185897.0,
>     1989: 156167015.0,
>     1990: 136766262.0,
>     1992: 658716349.0,
>     1993: 15668826.0,
>     1995: 710806752.0,
>     1996: 978717877.0,
>     1997: 2178045256.0}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need filter first by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), then aggregate `sum` and final `Series` reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df_genre_sum = (df_genre[df_genre['genre'].isin(genres)]
                 .groupby(['release_year', 'genre'])['revenue']
                 .sum()
                 .unstack())


df_genre_sum.plot()
```

Comment: The result is empty

Comment: Can you tell me why the `legends` to represent color of each genre is missing when I do : `plt.plot(df_genre_sum.index,df_genre_sum)
plt.title('Change in Revenue of Genre till 2015')
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('$ in 100 millions')`. https://imgur.com/a/VfUFYKf

Comment: Take a look at the image https://imgur.com/a/VfUFYKf . This small box tells us which genre has which color in the graph. this box doesn't show up when use `plt` code as mentioned in above comments

Comment: @ShashankVivek - Is possible create some sample data for testing? e.g. `df_genre_sum.head(20).to_dict()` ?

Comment: Updated my question. BTW, `plt.legend(genres)` did the trick :)

Comment: Super, you get solution. Also is possible use `plt.legend(df_genre_sum.columns)`

Comment: Cool, makes more sense to pass column names. Thanks :)